# How to convert quantlib.time.date.Date to pandas.tslib.Timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, quantlib

I have a list data.keys() which returns 
dict_keys([2016-09-27, 2016-09-28, 2016-09-29, 2016-09-30, 2016-09-26])

Data type for each of the element is quantlib.time.date.Date

How do I create an index for pandas with the above so that the index is of type pandas.tslib.Timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something like this might work:

dataframe.set_index = [ pandas.to_datetime(str(a)) for a in list(data.keys()) ]

but I get the following error:

KeyError: Timestamp('2016-09-27 00:00:00')
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Try this instead: `dataframe.index = pandas.to_datetime([str(a) for a in list(data.keys())])`